# Android sqlite where clause

Tags: android, sqlite

How to make this line work?

```
return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM GL_" + tablename + " WHERE " + KEY_GROUP_T + " = " + grp + " ORDER BY " + KEY_NAME_T + " COLLATE NOCASE", null);
```

> 04-23 17:58:26.701: E/AndroidRuntime(9212): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Baked_Goods:
>   , while compiling: SELECT * FROM GL_table4 WHERE grlist_group =
>   Baked_Goods ORDER BY grlist_name COLLATE NOCASE

This line is working but I want to do it with rawQuery:

```
return ourDatabase.query("GL_" + tablename, columns, KEY_GROUP_T + "= ?" , new String[]{grp}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Surround the value of `grlist_group` with single quote

Comment: WHERE " + KEY_GROUP_T + " = '" + grp + "' ORDER BY " +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work, you have to put single-quotes around your strings. Example:

```
return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM GL_" + tablename + " WHERE " + KEY_GROUP_T + " = '" + grp + "' ORDER BY " + KEY_NAME_T + " COLLATE NOCASE", null);
```

**Addition**

Waqas has a good point if `grp` is taken from the user's input, he is preventing a [SQL insertion attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  If you always define `grp`, then it isn't critical but good practice.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM GL_" + tablename + " WHERE " +
KEY_GROUP_T + " = " + grp + " ORDER BY " + KEY_NAME_T + " COLLATE NOCASE", null);
```

To this:

```
return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM GL_" + tablename + " WHERE " +
KEY_GROUP_T + " = ? ORDER BY " + KEY_NAME_T + " COLLATE NOCASE", new String[]{grp});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the single quote approach is correct, you can increase the speed of your query, and allows for better readability, and you can't forget the single quotes if you do this instead:

```
String [] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(grp)};
ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM GL_" + tablename + " WHERE " + KEY_GROUP_T + " = ?" + " ORDER BY " + KEY_NAME_T + " COLLATE NOCASE", selectionArgs);
```